# Adding two count queries in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

select  (SELECT COUNT(*) from table1) + (SELECT COUNT(*) from table2) as a

this is used to add two count queries in sql server 2008.

is there a better way?

Comment: It seems like a suitable way to me - is there an issue with it?

Comment: @user2864740 just wanted to know if there is a better way and an alternate way to do it. the query is working fine. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(F) FROM (
   SELECT COUNT(*) as F from table1
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT COUNT(*) as F from table2
) T
```

Comment: Can you please explain why is this better than the previous one? A query itself will not say anything to the OP.

Comment: It is just another one query which returns the same result as original was. To compare two queries we need to have the execution plans of both of them.